# Expanding Cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm trying to implement an expanding cell using [this](https://github.com/DylanVann/DatePickerCell)

here is my heightForRowAt indexPath

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0 : return 70
    case 1 :
        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

        if let datePickerCell = cell as? MyDatePickerCell {
            return datePickerCell.datePickerHeight()
        }
        return 260
    case 2 : return 80
    default : return 60
    }

}
```

The app gets stuck at

```
let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
```

the `UITableView` is embeded in a modal `UIViewController`

why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using a delegate since the table is embedded in a VC?

Comment: the tableview is the `MyDatePickerCell` delegate

Comment: But the class is UIViewController? Do you have an outlet for your table?

Comment: The parent viewcontroller is the delegate of the uitableview also

Comment: I think you have to provide more information (especially code examples) in order to get reasonable support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is that your tableView is looking for the heights of your cells before loading them in the first place. So you are trying to retrieve the cell before it is loaded, causing a crash.

To fix this you could create a dummy cell before loading the tableView and using that cell in heightForCell. That's more applicable for calculating variable heights for each cell though. In this case maybe hardcode the start height and then use the cell for heights after that.

Comment: I've added a dummy cell as a class var and set it in viewDidLoad : `datePickerCell = CreateDatePickerCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "MyDatePickerCell")` , still the app gets stuck

Comment: Where is it getting stuck now?

Comment: Stuck = nothing happens, it's not a crash. and the modal uiviewcontroller isn't presented

Comment: So it's not crashing, it's just not presenting. How do you know it is heightForRow that is the problem?

Comment: by replacing all the code in `case 1` by a simple `return 260`

Comment: Ok cool, so if it works when you hardcode it try my second option. Hardcode it for when it loads and then use the cell after.